# PHP - cURL get's old version of google

Tags: php, curl

When getting the Google site in cURL PHP I get the old Google page (The one with the blackbar and weird buttons). So is there a way to get the Google as it appears on google.com? My code:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url, $proxy) {
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;
}

echo file_get_contents_curl('https://www.google.com/', 'proxy:8080');
```

Thanks, if there is no way I am ok with the weird looking Google.

Comment: You have to set a User-Agent cookie, like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent: your favorite user agent']);`

Comment: I mean, User-Agent header, not cookie.

Comment: @Parziphal OK, thanks.